# How can I implement a loop in batch that creates a NEW output file after each iteration?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I use a java program (created by Pieter Vermeesch (see [here](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucfbpve/densityplotter/)) that requires a two-column CSV file as input and provides an option to output as a PDF. I have created a batch file that will iterate through all CSV files in a folder and run them through the program. The script is as follows:

```
for /r %%f in (*.csv) do java -jar densityplotter.jar binwidth=50 bandwidth=20 min=0 max=4000 in="%%f" out=Output.pdf
```

The arguments following the program are specific to the program of course, but I would like to know if there is a way to create a new file name for each PDF after each iteration because as it stands I am simply overwriting the Output.pdf file with each iteration. I would like to have something like Output1.pdf; Output2.pdf and so on. Or, even better would be to take the filename of the CSV specified by `%%f`.

Comment: read about modifiers in `for /?`. you can use for example `output="%%~nf.pdf"`

Comment: @Stephan Your example worked perfectly! Thank you very much. Do you know offhand of any good sites I can visit to learn more about these modifiers. I am very new to batch script (as I am sure you can tell). I've tried searching for a comprehensive "guide" but everything I've found is rather obscure.

Comment: Obscure? yeah, at the beginning it is. Until you got the point - then it becomes nice and easy. Read them in `for /?` and try them out. Also any combinations. At command prompt type `for /f %a in ("c:\folder\test\file.ext") do @echo ...` Replace `...` with `%~nxa`, `%~pa` and so on. Seeing the results teaches you more than reading descriptions.

Comment: @Stephan Thanks very much. Will certainly give it a go. This is really noob but what is `for /?` and where do I find it?

Comment: `/?` is a general "help" parameter. Nearly every command and program has it. Entering `for /?` on command line shows you the help pages with a short description of what it does and it's syntax. You also should check [this](http://ss64.com/nt/) site.

Comment: I read through the site and the CMD help. Quite self explanatory actually. Thanks again.